# Extracting dynamic content with node.js and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I want to console.log the content of web page with nodejs and phantomjs. This is my code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function(page) {
        return page.open("http://zehinz.com/test.html", function(status) {
            if (status === 'success') {
               //console.log the content of page with Javascript executed ???
            } else {
                console.log('some error');
                ph.exit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I output the dynamically rendered content of web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain PhantomJS one would use `page.content`, but since you're using a bridge, the `content` property has to be explicitly fetched from the PhantomJS process in the background. You can do this with [`page.get`](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details).

In your case, this is

```
page.get('content', function(content){
    console.log("Content", content);
    ph.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! But what can be wrong with this URL: http://www.morhipo.com/lacoste/markalar/0/32763/marka#pg=0&ps=60&ch=5025&os=0&stt=1064_32774%401057_32418&prv=1064&hf= It hangs

Comment: Register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.